# Display the selected of a Drop down list (javascript or jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to create a form where user have two option for image upload, Either  passport, an identity card, or a driver's license, but I want when the user chooses a passport box passport, if the selection of an identity card or a driver's license, two back and front

```
<form action="">

  <select >
    <option >PASSPORT</option>
    <option >ID CARD</option>
    <option >DRIVER LICENSE</option>
   </select><BR><BR>

  <input type="file" id="myFile" name="PASSPORT"><BR><BR>
  
  <input type="file" id="myFile" name="FRONT ID"><BR><BR>
    
  <input type="file" id="myFile" name="BACK ID"><BR><BR>
  
  <input type="file" id="myFile" name="BACK DRIVER LICENSE"><BR><BR>
  
  <input type="file" id="myFile" name="BACK DRIVER LICENSE"><BR><BR> 

  <input type="submit">  
  
</form>
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: Set a data attribute to your options and give the same class name to your inputs. Check when select change option, show and hide right inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it:

```js
(document.querySelector("select").onchange=ev=>{
  document.querySelectorAll("input[type=file]").forEach(e=>{
    e.style.display=ev.target.value.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ","")===e.className
      ? "block"
      : "none";
   })
})({target:{value:"passport"}});
```

```css
input[type=file] {margin:10px 0px}
```

```html
<form action="">
<select >
<option >PASSPORT</option>
<option >ID CARD</option>
<option >DRIVER LICENSE</option>
</select><BR><BR>
  <input type="file" class="passport" name="PASSPORT">  
  <input type="file" class="idcard"   name="FRONT ID">    
  <input type="file" class="idcard" name="BACK ID">  
  <input type="file" class="driverlicense" name="FRONT DRIVER LICENSE">  
  <input type="file" class="driverlicense" name="BACK DRIVER LICENSE">
  <input type="submit">  
</form>
```

I replaced your invalid `id` attributes with a `class` attribute and attached an event listener on the `select` element. As soon as the event is fired, the value of the select box is used to the `style.display` attribute of the input elements to either "block" or "none".

By putting the whole function definition in parentheses `()` and appending the argument `({target:{value:"passport"}})` after it I effectively simulate the firing of an event with a fake "event object"-argument containing a single attribute/sub-attribute: `target.value == "passport"`. This will make the first input group visible while hiding all the others.